# How to present Phoca Download's categories and items as a sitemap on the sidebar

Tags: joomla-3.x

I searched a Plug-In or Extension for Joomla! to present the Phoca Download Plug-In's Sitemap on the right sidebar with categories and it's entries.

The Problem is I can't find any plugin like that anywhere. Is there any alternative Sitemap to display the Phoca Download on right sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough.

If you are looking for a module to show component's content in a sidebar or somewhere else on site, you can find few modules on [Phoca's extension download index](http://www.phoca.cz/download/category/68-phoca-download).

I guess that [Phoca Download Tree Module](http://www.phoca.cz/download/category/42-phoca-download-tree-module) is just what doctor prescribed. I have never used Phoca before, but it sounds right.

Otherwise, if you are looking for some SiteMap plugin (for OSMap or JSiteMap) to show Phoca Download links in whole site map for Google indexing, I am not aware of such a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.phoca.cz/phocadownload-plugin, you can display Phoca Download categories and files using the following syntax:

```
{phocadownload view=category|id=35|target=b}

{phocadownload view=file|id=280}
```

This syntax can be inserted into a Custom HTML module and displayed in any module position (e.g. the right sidebar).

When editing the Custom HTML module, remember to set "Prepare Content" = "Yes" under the Options tab.